# Boot loop persists after changing power supply

Tags: power-supply

This week, after updating my Raspberry Pi B+ (running Arch Linux) to fix the Dirty COW bug, it turned itself off and when I went to check it, it was stuck in a boot loop.

I searched about it and found out that it was caused by a defective power supply. So I just cut the USB cable I was using and soldered it directly into a computer power supply plug (soldered black into black, red into red, ignored green and white wires).

After I plugged it in my Pi, the issue persisted. It boots up, then after ~3-5 seconds it reboots again, and keeps doing this.

What could this be? Could this be an issue with the USB cable I'm using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the issue by changing the USB cable I was using. Somehow the old cable stopped providing enough amperage to supply the Pi's needs.

Comment: Highly plausible. Its not that the cable stopped providing the required power... It never provided the required power :)  It was all an illusion - any way. Good quality cables are always recommended. Please mark your answer as accepted. Glad you got it working.